# How to clear cached after I finished saving data?

Tags: c#, asp.net, browser-cache, outputcache, clear-cache

I'm just new ASP .NET, and I would like to know on how can I clear all the data entries after saving it and redirected to other page?

I have tried this on my HTML page,

```
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1">
```

and also this on my Code Behind page,

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        if(!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Server);
            Response.Expires = -1;
            Response.AddHeader("Pragma", "No-Cache");
            Response.CacheControl = "no-cache";
        }
    }
```

but still the data I encoded / page appears whenever I go back.

Please help. Greatly appreciate. Thank you. :D

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-1));
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
```

Comment: I go from other page but after I click 'BACK' still the page was populated. I wanted the page1 after I go to page2, and I click back the page1 will turns to its original view. Thx for the help anyways.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the browser to keep form fields populated, you can set the HTML attribute `autocomplete` to `off`.

```
<input type="text" name="myfield" autocomplete="off" />
```

Comment: I go from other page but after I click 'BACK' still the page was populated. I wanted the page1 after I go to page2, and I click back the page1 will turns to its original view. Thx for the help anyways.